# How to set the docker volume in windows?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I have a folder `test` with a `yaml file` inside.

I have a following yaml file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    volumes:
      - './test/docker_volumn/mariadb_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_wordpress
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_wordpress
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  wordpress_data:
    driver: local
```

When I try to run `docker-compose up -d`, it gives me error:

```
ERROR: for test_mariadb_1  Cannot create container for service mariadb: invalid volume specification: 'D:\test\docker_volumn\mariadb_data:/bitnami:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: d:\test\docker_volumn\mariadb_data
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things to get you started:

You got a typo in your volume definition **"volumn"**

```
volumes:
  - './test/docker_volumn/mariadb_data:/bitnami'
```

---

Does the folder `D:/test/docker_volumn/mariadb_data` exist on your host?
If not, create it beforehand (preferably without the typo ;) ).

---

Since you are writing a docker-compose file based on `version: '3'` I recommend to 
 use the long syntax to define volumes as described in the docker-compose file reference to explicitly define the type of the volume in question.

```
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: ./test/docker_volumn/mariadb_data
    target: /bitnami
```

**Source**

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Comment: I have D:\test folder only